# How to print feature values after transformation inside tensorflow model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, data-science, tensorboard

How can I see the value of final features that are being trained inside tensorflow model. Like in the below case I am trying to multi-hot my column 'x' and I want to see how the features are going to my model.

This is very easy to do in sklearn but being new to Tensorflow I dont understand how is it possible.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd

data = {'x':['a c', 'a b', 'b c'], 'y': [1, 1, 0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
Y = df['y']
X = df.drop('y', axis=1)
indicator_features = [tf.feature_column.indicator_column(categorical_column=
      tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(key = 'x', 
                                                 vocabulary_list = ['a','b','c']))]
model = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(feature_columns=indicator_features,
                                                              model_dir = "/tmp/samplemodel")
training_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(x = X,
                                                    y=Y,
                                                    batch_size=64,
                                                    shuffle= True,
                                                    num_epochs = None)

model.train(input_fn=training_input_fn,steps=1000)
```

Comment: Can you post how would you do it in sklearn so I can try to replicate it?

Comment: Have you tried tf.Print() ?

Comment: @Sharky... i don't understand how tf.Print() can be used here.. any ideas ?

Comment: @gorjan.. I could simply do something like this example ... https://chrisalbon.com/machine_learning/preprocessing_structured_data/one-hot_encode_features_with_multiple_labels/

Comment: @KundanKumar, You can pass any tensor to it. I'm not certain whether it will work with tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn, but You may try to pass your 'x' to it like tf.Print(x, [x])

Comment: I have posted by solution/workaround. Still need to figure out in the below example if my categorical column is space separated how do get the multi hot encoding for it.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to print the values by enabling the eager execution in tensorflow. 
Posting my solution below. Welcome for any other ideas as well.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.feature_column as fc 
import pandas as pd

PATH = "/tmp/sample.csv"

tf.enable_eager_execution()

COLUMNS = ['education','label']
train_df = pd.read_csv(PATH, header=None, names = COLUMNS)

#train_df['education'] = train_df['education'].str.split(" ")
def easy_input_function(df, label_key, num_epochs, shuffle, batch_size):
  label = df[label_key]
  ed = tf.string_split(df['education']," ")
  df['education'] = ed
  ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(df),label))
  if shuffle:
    ds = ds.shuffle(10000)
  ds = ds.batch(batch_size).repeat(num_epochs)
  return ds

ds = easy_input_function(train_df, label_key='label', num_epochs=5, shuffle=False, batch_size=5)


for feature_batch, label_batch in ds.take(1):
  print('Some feature keys:', list(feature_batch.keys())[:5])
  print()
  print('A batch of education  :', feature_batch['education'])
  print()
  print('A batch of Labels:', label_batch )
  print(feature_batch)

education_vocabulary_list = [
    'Bachelors', 'HS-grad', '11th', 'Masters', '9th', 'Some-college',
    'Assoc-acdm', 'Assoc-voc', '7th-8th', 'Doctorate', 'Prof-school',
    '5th-6th', '10th', '1st-4th', 'Preschool', '12th']  
education = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list('education', vocabulary_list=education_vocabulary_list)

fc.input_layer(feature_batch, [fc.indicator_column(education)])
```